# How do I draw a line to connect one entry to another within a tabular environment?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I have a `tabular` environment intended as an exercise in a textbook.  I want it to look like this:

> [image: A simple tabular environment, with the desired line drawn by hand in orange]

And the student is meant to complete the exercise by connecting the remaining lines.

**Question**: How do I draw a line to connect one entry to another within a tabular environment?

I'm open to alternatives that can achieve the same objective: indicating that the student should connect the cell on the left-hand side to the corresponding answer on the right-hand side.

Here's the code I'm using for the table:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lcl}
 letter & & number \\
 \hline
 a & \qquad\qquad\qquad & 3 \\
 b & \qquad\qquad\qquad & 4 \\
 c & \qquad\qquad\qquad & 2 \\
 d & \qquad\qquad\qquad & 1 \\
 e & \qquad\qquad\qquad & 5 \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

I'm using XeLaTeX to compile (since I have Chinese fonts).

In the past I've use Tikz baseline/overlay for similar jobs, but it's been a while, and I can't get it to work:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{mynode/.style={draw=none,fill=none,rectangle,anchor=base}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lcl}
 letter & & number \\
 \hline
 a & \tikz[baseline]{\node[mynode] (A) {};} \qquad\qquad\qquad \tikz[baseline]{\node[mynode] (3) {};} & 3 \\
 b & \tikz[baseline]{\node[mynode] (B) {};} \qquad\qquad\qquad \tikz[baseline]{\node[mynode] (4) {};} & 4 \\
 c & \tikz[baseline]{\node[mynode] (C) {};} \qquad\qquad\qquad \tikz[baseline]{\node[mynode] (2) {};} & 2 \\
 d & \tikz[baseline]{\node[mynode] (D) {};} \qquad\qquad\qquad \tikz[baseline]{\node[mynode] (1) {};} & 1 \\
 e & \tikz[baseline]{\node[mynode] (E) {};} \qquad\qquad\qquad \tikz[baseline]{\node[mynode] (5) {};} & 5 \\
 \hline

 \tikz[overlay] \path[line width=1pt,-stealth,out=0,in=-90] (A) edge (1);
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

This gives me an arrow, but it doesn't connect the nodes:

[image: output of above code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget `remember picture` option.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{mynode/.style={draw=none,fill=none,rectangle,anchor=base}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lcl}
 letter & & number \\
 \hline
 \tikz[remember picture,baseline]{\node[mynode] (A) {a};} & \qquad\qquad\qquad & \tikz[remember picture,baseline]{\node[mynode] (3) {3};}\\
 \tikz[remember picture,baseline]{\node[mynode] (B) {b};} & \qquad\qquad\qquad & \tikz[remember picture,baseline]{\node[mynode] (4) {4};}\\
 \tikz[remember picture,baseline]{\node[mynode] (C) {c};} & \qquad\qquad\qquad & \tikz[remember picture,baseline]{\node[mynode] (2) {2};}\\
 \tikz[remember picture,baseline]{\node[mynode] (D) {d};} & \qquad\qquad\qquad & \tikz[remember picture,baseline]{\node[mynode] (1) {1};}\\
 \tikz[remember picture,baseline]{\node[mynode] (E) {e};} & \qquad\qquad\qquad & \tikz[remember picture,baseline]{\node[mynode] (5) {5};}\\
 \hline

 \tikz[remember picture,overlay] \draw[line width=1pt,-stealth,out=0,in=-180] (A) to (1);
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]